# Asymmetric photoluminescence spectra

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, spectroscopy

Why do photoluminescence spectra have asymmetric lineshapes as those here http://www.scielo.br/img/revistas/bjp/v37n4/a04fig01.gif
or here: http://www.oxford-instruments.com/industries-and-applications/research/optical-spectroscopy/photoluminescence?

Comment: Check out (black-body radiation)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation]. Recall that photon energy is inversely proportional to wavelength.

Comment: Thanks, but the images from my second link and yours are reverse to each other, though the x-axis is in terms of wavelengths. So maybe photoluminewscense and black-body radiation have different nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular example the photoluminescence is of quantum wells.

The reason for the asymmetry is because the density of states is not symmetric. At the low energy side the density of states has a excition Lorentzian line shape to the absorptivity. At higher energies the density of states becomes step like.

The photoluminescence intensity,

$$
I(E) \propto g(E) 
$$

Where $g(E)$ is the density of states and photon energy $E$.

*(Note this is not strictly true, because the PL intensity is proportional to the joint density of states the the probability of the final and initial state are occupies and unoccupied, respectively. However, it illustrates the point I'm making to a reasonable degree)*.

So when the density of states is not symmetrical nor will the photoluminescence be.

I hope that gives you a few hints at least.

Comment: That feels right, thanks. Could you please provide me with some images of that density of states you were describing?

Comment: Google is your friend. https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=quantum+well+density+of+states